# git submodule update via ssh error

Tags: python, django, github, clone, cpanel

I cloned the application commcare-hq after installing python and django in my cpanel. here's the link: https://github.com/dimagi/commcare-hq but whenever i enter the following command

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

i get the following error

```
fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/dimagi/xml2json.git' into submodule path 
'/home/hcdcnetl/myProject/commcare-hq/submodules/xml2json' failed
Failed to clone 'submodules/xml2json'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/home/hcdcnetl/myProject/commcare- 
hq/corehq/apps/hqmedia/static/hqmedia/MediaUploader'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Connection refused
github.com[1: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection refused
```

Comment: Have you properly configured the RSA-SHA in GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

`git://github.com` is not an SSH URL, it is a Git-protocol URL.

Try

```
git config --global url."git@github.com/".insteadOf git://github.com/
```

Any `git://github.com/` will be replaced by the SSH URL `git@github.com/...`